# Java SQL output format table result

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I got everything working and it prints the right result with header (column name) and value. However I wanted to change a plain and unorganized result into a really nice output table format just like MySql table result with dash lines from query. How do I do that?

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM quarter");
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
{
    System.out.print(rsMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + " ");
}
System.out.println();
while (rs.next())
{
    for(int e = 1; e <= rsMetaData.getColumnCount(); e++)
    {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(e) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.format()` method with appropriate [format string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

For instance,

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
{
    sb.append(String.format("| %-10s",rsMetaData.getColumnLabel(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have function for that. Change the parameter as need while calling.

```
public static void printHeader(ResultSet rs, char symbol, int width) throws Exception 
{
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int nCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for(int i = 1; i <= nCols; ++i)
          System.out.printf("%-10s ", rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));

     System.out.printf("\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        System.out.printf("%c", symbol);
}

//call <br>
printHeader(rs,'-',70);
```